# Does Eloquent relation sync also remove?

Tags: laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

When updating a model and I sync a relationship, if I don't pass in all the ids that already exist, will that relationship be removed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You decide: `sync` has 2nd parameter that defaults to `true` and is responsible for detaching:

```
$model->relationship()->sync([1,2,3]);

$model->relationship()->sync([4,5,6]); // attached [4,5,6], detached [1,2,3]
$model->relationship()->getRelatedIds(); // [4,5,6]

// but:
$model->relationship()->sync([4,5,6], false); // attached [4,5,6], detached []
$model->relationship()->getRelatedIds(); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: But if I remove all the Tags, `sync()` does not do anything at all. How can you make it work in this case? For example, if previously you have `[1,2,3]` inside the relational table and want to make a `sync([])` because you have removed all the tags from the Select2. How do you delete all the tags then?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes it does. I could not find any documentation that in fact stated that.

lets say you have 2 tables: "authors" and "books", with a pivot table "book_authors".

when creating a new author:

```
$author_id =2;
$author->books()->sync(array(1,4,5,15));
```

Now you have a 4 entries in that pivot table "book_authors":

```
author_id  book_id
2          1
2          4
2          5
2          15
```

Now update:

```
$author_id =2;
$author->books()->sync(array(1,15));
```

now "book_authors" is:

```
author_id  book_id
    2          1
    2          15
```

Comment: I can confirm. `sync()` method is supposed to remove relations that don't exist anymore and keep relations that are still relevant.

Comment: But if I remove all the Tags, sync() does not do anything at all. How can you make it work in this case? For example, if previously you have [1,4,5,15] inside the relational table and want to make a sync([]) because you have removed all the tags from the Select2. How do you delete all the tags then?

Comment: You can use relation to delete it like. `$author->books->delete();`