# laravel: prevent duplicate doublet in pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot

I searched before posting and I found this

[Preventing Laravel adding multiple records to a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472128/preventing-laravel-adding-multiple-records-to-a-pivot-table)

However if I try that solution I got an exception regarding query builder use of contains()

I need to check if an item is already attached to a user in the pivot table so to prevent multiple posts:

this one is the line I tried:

```
if (!Auth::user()->collected_item()->contains($id)) {

 Auth::user()->collected_item()->attach($id);    

}
```

but as said that doesn't work.
So I built a query to check if the line user_id / id exists already in db, if resulting var is empty attach item else print "already there".. this way works however can it be simplified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing Laravel adding multiple records to a pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472128/preventing-laravel-adding-multiple-records-to-a-pivot-table)

Answer (score 3):

oh damn! I solved it changing:

```
if (!Auth::user()->collected_item()->contains($id))
```

to

```
if (! Auth::user()->collected_item->contains($id) )
```

Comment: Perhaps this would do without making that extra check using `contains()` first: `Auth::user()->collected_item()->sync([$id], $detach = false);`. Important note about 2nd param `$detach = false` is that `sync()` would otherwise remove all rows except the one having `$id`.

Comment: Thanks but that would remove all the other items attached to the user.

Comment: As I've already mentioned: passing `false` as the second argument to `sync()` does not detach other records. See Eloquent API: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_sync or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24211767/197487